# Gnome Shell Extension Counterpart in ElementaryOS

Tags: desktop

I am looking for a status bar network speed indicator, which exists in gnome environment. See: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/

Does anyone know how to get same kind of functionality in ElementaryOS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[indicator-netspeed-unity](https://github.com/GGleb/indicator-netspeed-unity)

[image: Something like this?]

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/netspeed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-netspeed-unity
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use the System Load Indicator. 
https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload